# How to create a dictionary in java

Tags: java, dictionary

Can i get some help on creating a dictionary in java? I tried to create it as

```
Dictionary<String, Integer> dict = new Dictionary<String, Integer>();
```

but I am not able to run it because the ide does not show what went wrong, but greys out the run button.

Comment: Does the object Dictionary exists somewhere? If not you have to create an API called Dictionary with all the methods you need before you can use it.

Comment: Yes i imported it.

Comment: In Java, this is called a `Map`. A common implementation is `HashMap`.

Comment: 1 thing that could help is showing what the errors are.

Comment: Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: _"but it shows errors."_ - you should show those errors. Otherwise its nearly impossible for us to pinpoint the problem and provide help. Please read [ask]. Downvoted and voting to close because of that.

Comment: Please add some further explanation to your code - why are you unable to run that single line of code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the [java API documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/index.html) for this.

By using that, or some basic web searching, you'd find that java has the concept of a 'dictionary', but it is called a Map. There are various implementations with different properties. For example, if you want it to sort itself continuously on the string key:

```
Map<String, Integer> dict = new TreeMap<>();
```

The most basic version is:

```
Map<String, Integer> dict = new HashMap<>();
```

NB: Yeah, there is `java.util.Dictionary`. However, that's why those docs are so important: The [Dictionary doc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Dictionary.html) clearly states:

> NOTE: This class is obsolete. New implementations should implement the Map interface, rather than extending this class.

So, don't try to use it.

Comment: There is actually a Dictionnary class in java it's under java.util

Comment: What's the difference between "TreeMap" and "HashMap"?

Comment: @JeannotMn ha! Wow, yeah, there is. I'll update the answer.

Comment: @BoomCode10010011 A TreeMap is like a phonebook: If you want to add, say, "Mr. Anthony" to the book, you go to the middle, see "Miyagi", and then you can discard the 'top half' of the phonebook - the place to insert is in the first half. So you go to half-of-the-first-half, etc. keep going until you find the place to add it. That's a TreeMap - it inserts entries based on their sorting order. a HashMap just stores things unsorted (and fast).

Answer (score 0):

In Java you use a `Map` as a Dictionary.

```
Map<Integer, String> dict = new HashMap<>();
```

Comment: Does it use the same key, value concept?

Comment: Yes it does. In this example `Integer` is the key, and `String` is the value.
You can check out the documentation on the `Map` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), and the `Hashmap` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html)